# How to center the specific part of a text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm currently learning bootstrap to design a website. And I'm now creating a profile page of a user. There will be fields (e. g. name, email etc.) and values against them (on one line, if the screen size allows). So I want the field to be at the left, and the value at the center, but I can't find out how to implement it using bootstrap classes and css, if needed. So here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2e9370a952.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(to right,  #7A96E9, #BFAEE0);
            text-align: center;
        }
        .profile-info {
            background: white;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style="height: 100vh">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="profile-info p-4">
                <h1 class="mb-4">Profile</h1> 
                <div class="text-start">
                    <p><strong>Email</strong><span class="value">example@example.com</span></p>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So here I want "Email" (in the tag "strong") to be at the left of the parent "profile-info" and the span (with class "value") to be centered in that parent.

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. Because I want not the whole text to be centered, but only the label field (not value). When trying this I saw either the entire text centered, or the value centered but on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text-Align` the entire parent to `center`, and then `position` `absolute`ly with the combination of `left:0` and `right:0` the `value` class, and `float` the `strong` to the `left`, Like so:

```css
.text-start p {
  text-align: center
}

.text-start strong {
  float: left;
}

.value {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2e9370a952.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #7A96E9, #BFAEE0);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .profile-info {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="profile-info p-4">
          <h1 class="mb-4">Profile</h1>
          <div class="text-start">
            <p><strong>Email</strong><span class="value">example@example.com</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```